# Attribute Change of Macro Variable in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I have a macro variable like **&a** having value of **(1234.45)***. I am trying to replace the **(** and **)** from the macro and replace them with a **negative** mark since its a negative number.

```
%let a=(1234.45)
```

Some of the options which I have appplied are

```
%macro test1;

%if %substr(&a,1,1) = '(' %then %do; 
        %let b=%substr(&a,1,'-')
%end;

%mend;

%test1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is numeric conversion and best handled in a data step.  If for some reason you really need a macro variable, use SYMPUT.

```
%let a=(1234.45);

data _null_;
x=input("&a.",comma10.);
call symputx("b",x);
run;
%put &=a &=b;
```